# Maximo Anywhere asset barcode scanning issue

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, barcode, maximo, maximo-anywhere

We have installed Maximo Anywhere 7.6.3 apps in Android tablets and we are trying to test Barcode scanning feature for Asset data manager app and asset audit apps.

In our organization we have some assets naming starts with equal sign and if we scan the barcode of an asset we are getting a value with equal "=" symbol.

For example: Asset Number: **=CRL110.CUS001**

In Maximo we can't create an asset starting with equal sign"=" as per below tech note so we are unable to use barcode feature.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/bmxaa4041e-key-field-value-contains-invalid-data

Can anyone suggest any workaround for this ?  which file we have change/extend to skip = sign while searching Maximo database for the asset.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse out the = sign does it still return the appropriate value from the database, and more importantly, are they all still unique? If so, I'd look at dropping the "=" sign, and writing a parser on the Anywhere side that detects and removes it if scanned.

Comment: Kasey, 
Thank you for your response and help.
Yes they are all unique values.

Any help regarding which Java/JavaScript file we have extended/Change in Maximo Anywhere to drop "=" sign from scanned code ?

Comment: I'd write a custom handler, and then reference that on the datachange if the field that you are using as your barcode field. 
Here's an example:        
 `<eventHandler class="custom.handlers.PrintViewHandler" event="datachange" id="Transfers.PrintView_Labels_checkboxeventHandlers_click" method="clickLabels"/>`